# How to highlight the nearest nodes when a group is selected

Tags: r, visualization, visnetwork

When I select a group of nodes from the dropdown, I want the nearest nodes one degree away to also be highlighted. Currently, only the nodes in the group are highlighted.

I thought the highlightNearest with degree = 1 would help, but that only seems to affect when a single node is selected, not when a group is selected.

```
library(visNetwork)
nb <- 10
nodes <- data.frame(
  id = 1:nb, label = paste("Label", 1:nb),
  group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], nb, replace = TRUE), value = 1:nb,
  title = paste0("<p>", 1:nb, "<br>Tooltip !</p>"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(8, 2, 7, 6, 1, 8, 9, 4, 6, 2),
  to = c(3, 7, 2, 7, 9, 1, 5, 3, 2, 9),
  value = rnorm(nb, 10), label = paste("Edge", 1:nb),
  title = paste0("<p>", 1:nb, "<br>Edge Tooltip !</p>")
)

visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "500px", width = "100%") %>%
  visOptions(
    selectedBy = "group",
    highlightNearest = TRUE,
    nodesIdSelection = TRUE
  ) %>%
  visLayout(randomSeed = 123)
```

When I select group A, I see nodes "Label 4", "Label 9", and "Lable 10" highlighted. The edges touching those nodes are also highlighted. Screenshot:

[image]

I want the nearest nodes to also be highlighted: "Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 5" and "Label 3" Screenshot with hand-drawn arrows pointed at the extra 4 nodes that should be highlighted:

[image]

If I click on nodes "Label 4" & "Label 9" directly, the nearest nodes are highlighted like I want them to be. I want this same highlighting behavior to also work when I select a group. Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible thanks to a recent enhancement by [bthieurmel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2561017/bthieurmel) on [Github here](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/335). Until the enhancement makes it into CRAN, you'll need to install visNetwork from Github, in order to get this to work.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("datastorm-open/visNetwork")
```

Then, update the code from the question, replacing `selectedBy = "group"` with

```
selectedBy = list(variable = "group", highlight = TRUE)
```